# AWS instance scheduled for retirement - What is simplest resolution?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Got this email from AWS, "Amazon EC2 Instance scheduled for retirement". If you use AWS heavily, you've probably seen this email. Here's the meat of it:

> We have important news about your account.  EC2 has detected degradation of the underlying hardware hosting one or more of your Amazon EC2 instances in the us-east-1 region. Due to this degradation, your instance(s) could already be unreachable. Running instances will be stopped or terminated after 12:00AM UTC on YYYY-MM-DD. The affected instances are listed below:
>
> i-12345678
>
> *<...other stuff, not relevant to my question...>*
>
> What do you need to do?
>
> If you can still access the instance, we recommend the following:
>
> *<...other stuff, not relevant to my question...>*
>
> - If your instance's root device is an EBS volume, you can replace the instance by creating an AMI of your instance, and launching a new instance from the AMI. For more information please see Amazon Machine Images... *other stuff, not relevant to my question*

The AWS docs, and the email itself, indicate **I must create an AMI from the current instance** to resolve this. I've heard, though, that simply stopping the instance and restarting it will migrate it to new hardware.

Is this true?

If simply stopping/starting won't solve this, is there a simple solution for this that isn't as clunky as creating an AMI and launching from that?

Answer (score 6):

I've received several of these from AWS over the years, and in each case a stop/start cycle was enough to get it on different hardware.

That said, it would be best to contact AWS support and verify that a stop/start will be sufficient in this case. Regardless, it's a good idea to make an AMI anyway, as a last resort.

Comment: How can I tell that an instance is on new hardware?

Comment: If the alert goes away. But seriously - if you value the existence of this server, contact AWS support.

Comment: lol, thanks! silly aws and their silly idea that servers are ephemeral

Comment: It's not that silly actually, as it forces you to build resilient infrastructure that can be deployed programmatically. Which is a very good thing.

Comment: For closure: I did contact AWS support and they confirm that stop/start the instance will work as I described.

Comment: Same here, a stop/start solved the issue.
My AWS hardware actually crashed, it was gone for 10 minutes then I received that message.
I guess it's a good idea to do a restart as soon as possible to avoid a possible data corruption during the waiting period.

Comment: Here's a script I wrote which we use to automate handling of these retirement/degradation notices: https://github.com/snobear/ec2-retirement-bulk-fix

Comment: I am scared of this : Please note that any data on your local instance-store volumes will not be preserved when you stop and start your instance. Can anyone please elaborate, what they are saying