# EC2 instance seems to have gone back in time

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I received an e-mail last week with the following:

> We have important news about your account.  EC2 has detected
>   degradation of the underlying hardware hosting one or more of your
>   Amazon EC2 instances in the eu-west-1 region. Due to this degradation,
>   your instance(s) could already be unreachable. Running instances will
>   be stopped or terminated after 12:00AM UTC on 2015-12-01. The affected
>   instances are listed below:
>
> i-xxxxxxxx

After some Googling, I came across this - [AWS instance scheduled for retirement - What is simplest resolution?](https://serverfault.com/questions/728392/aws-instance-scheduled-for-retirement-what-is-simplest-resolution) - which suggested that I needed to reboot the EC2 to provision it to new hardware.

I did that over the weekend but this morning our client is reporting that DB data is missing. Almost like the server has been restored to an earlier backup. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.  Probably time to hit the backups.

Comment: How is your data stored?

Comment: This was all due to old volumes re-attaching themselves to the EC2 one it booted back up. Once I de-attached the old volumes and attached only the most recent volume, the box was back to normal.

The reason for having multiple volumes was that I had to do a couple of disk resizes in the servers lifetime.